# Prove that the Hirsch rank of a group is unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

A group $G$ is called polycyclic if there exists a subnormal series $G = G_0 \unlhd G_1 \unlhd \dots \unlhd G_n = \{e\}$ whose factors are cyclic. Prove that arbitrary two polycyclic series of $G$ have the same number of infinite factors (Hirsch rank).

What I'm thinking is to consider two polycyclic series with different number of infinite factors, and then try to get a contradiction. However, I don't seem to be getting anywhere with that approach. I would like a hint as to how to solve this, but not a complete solution.

Comment: This is a standard result. See, for example, D.J. Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, 5.4.13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an arbitrary group, define $c(G)$ as the (possibly infinite) supremum of lengths $n$ of chains $H_0\le \dots \le H_n$ of subgroups with $H_i/H_{i-1}$ infinite for all $i$.

Then a simple argument shows that $c(G)$ is additive under extensions: $c(G)=c(N)+c(G/N)$ for every normal subgroup of $G$. Indeed $\ge$ is trivial and $\le$ uses the fact that if $H\subset L$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H$ has infinite index in $L$, then either $H\cap N$ has infinite index in $L\cap N$, or $p(H)$ has infinite index in $p(L)$, where $p$ is the projection $G\to G/N$.

Since $c(F)=0$ for $F$ finite and $c(\mathbf{Z})=1$, it follows that in a subnormal series with cyclic quotients for a group $G$, the number of infinite cyclic factors is equal to $c(G)$, which depends only on $G$.

Comment: I'm not clear on the "$\geq$" direction. You take a chain in $G/N$, lift it to a chain in $G$, and append a chain in $N$ to the bottom. But there's a link between these chains: how do you know the last the term in the top chain has infinite index over the first term in the bottom chain? Am I missing an obvious reason that this won't happen? Does the case $c(G/N)=0$ have to be ruled out independently?

Comment: @Ehsaan I don't lift, I pull back. If $p=c(N)$ and $q=c(G/N)$, I have chains $1=A_0\le A_1\le\dots A_p=N$ and $1=B_0/N\le \dots B_q/N=G/N$, where each has infinite index in the next one. Writing $B_i=A_{p+i}$, we get the chain $A_0\le\dots \le A_{p+q}$ where each has infinite index in the next one (notably $A_{p-1}\le A_p=B_0\le B_1$).

Comment: I think we agree that one takes the preimage under the quotient map. I'm still not sure I get it. What I don't see is why we can always assume that the chain has the trivial group at the bottom (e.g. assuming $B_0=N$ or $A_0=1$). There's a little argument to be made there, no? Similarly, you can only assume that the top term $A_p$ has finite index in $N$, not that it is equal to $N$.

Comment: If at the bottom you don't have the trivial group, just replace the group at the bottom with the trivial group. Similarly at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution: if $G$ has two polycyclic series, then by Schreier's theorem they have equivalent refinements (so the refinements would have the same number of infinite cyclic factors).

Claim: a refinement of a polycyclic series does not change the number of infinite factors.

Proof: Suppose the term $K \unlhd L$, where $K/L$ is infinite cyclic. Then consider arbitrary refinement $K \unlhd M \unlhd L$. By the third isomorphism theorem, $K/M \cong (K/L)/(M/L)$. We have that $M/L \leq K/L$, so $M/L$ must be infinite cyclic. $K/M$ is isomorphic to a factor group of $\mathbb{Z}$, and is hence finite. So the refinement has the same number of infinite factors as the original polycyclic series.

Hence any two polycyclic series of a group $G$ have the same number of infinite factors.